# Self-Referential Association with :include of data on main table (rails 2.3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a self referential association like this:

```
class Influencer < ActiveRecord::Base

 has_many :followers, :class_name => 'Following', :foreign_key => 'influencer_id'
 has_many :following, :class_name => 'Following', :foreign_key => 'follower_id'
```

on my influencer table I have a field called "external_identifier"

I want to check my followers for a given external_identifier, so normally I would do an :include so it does a join.

I tried:

```
myinfluencer.followers.find(:first, :include => 'influencers', :conditions => ["influencers.external_identifier = ?","934394343434"])
```

but it errors with "influencers" is not an association, I also tried "followers", neither seem to work properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `:include => :follower`.

`myinfluencer.followers` returns a has_many association, so when you are joining in order to test a condition on the related model (Influencer), you need to use the `belongs_to` side of the association, which in this case is `belongs_to :follower`.

Answer (score 0):

`include` takes the name of an association, so you would have to give it either `followers` or `following`, depending on what you're trying to join.

Comment: tried that also, in this case it doesnt make sense either because followers and following get the relation record called "Following"